# Can't publish Azure Function from Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-functions

I am trying to publish my Azure Functions from Visual Studio for Mac (8.10.6, build 10) and it does not work.

Everything works fine when running `func start` (obviously running from Visual Studio does not work as my Macbook has M1 processor and that is not supported yet).

**What's more, when I created new function from template, I can publish it normally.** I've read that it could be because of antivirus working on machine, but I expect that if I can publish other functions then it should work fine.

When trying to publish from Visual Studio I am getting:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.302/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): error : Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.)
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.302/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): error : 
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.302/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): error : Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.302/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): error : Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: results. Line 1, position 550.
```

Do you have any ideas why could that be?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a firewall/access issue, check that VS is trusted and has access to connect to the internet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/install-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy-server?view=vsmac-2019